# Is the Householder transformation $H(v)=I-2vv^T/v^Tv$ continuous differentiable?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, continuity

Let $H(v)=I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}$ be the Householder function that maps a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^d$  to the Householder matrix $I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$.

Note that $H(0)=I-2\frac{vv^T}{0}$ is not defined. I think this can be fixed as follows. I think that $\lim_{v\rightarrow 0}H(v)=\lim_{v\rightarrow 0}I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}=I$ because $\lim_{v\rightarrow 0}\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}=0$ (might be wrong). If true, then change $H(v)$ at $v=0$ such that $H(0):=\lim_{v\rightarrow 0}H(v)=I$.

Q1. Did I make any mistakes above? Is it true that $\lim_{v\rightarrow 0}\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}=0$?

Q2. Is the modified $H(v)$ continuous?

Q3. Is the modified $H(v)$ continuous differentiable?

Comment: The transformation is used in, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00188 equation (8) and they claim it is smooth* except on a subset of zero Lebesgue measure. * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness

Comment: The limit is not $0$, as can easily be seen in the case $d=1$, because then for $v\neq 0$, $\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv} = \frac{v^2}{v^2} = 1$, so the limit as $v\to 0$ is $1$.

Comment: The function does not have a limit at $v = 0$. For any unit vector $u$, the limit of $H(tu)$ as the scalar $t$ approaches zero is $H(u)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is not $0$, as can easily be seen in the case $d=1$, because then for $v\neq 0$, $\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv} = \frac{v^2}{v^2} = 1$, so the limit as $v\to 0$ is $1$.

If $d>1$, the situation is much worse because the limit doesn't even exist. Let $\xi= \begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ such that $x^2+y^2 = 1$. Then,
\begin{align}
f(\xi):= \frac{\xi \xi^T}{\langle \xi,\xi\rangle} &=
\begin{pmatrix}
x^2 & xy \\
xy & y^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
So, $\lim\limits_{s\to 0}f(s\xi) = \lim\limits_{s\to 0}f(\xi) = f(\xi) = \begin{pmatrix}
x^2 & xy \\
xy & y^2
\end{pmatrix}$, and this clearly depends on $\xi$, so the limit doesn't exist.

Since the limit doesn't exist for $d>1$, the given $H$ doesn't even have a continuous extension let alone a continuously differentiable extension.